# Create new document and store reference to said document in another collection

Tags: mongodb

In a `Project` you can create a `Task`.

I want to store a reference to a project's tasks in `Project`, as an array of `ObjectId`s:

```
Project: {
    name: 'My Project',
    tasks:[ObjectId('...'), ObjectId('...')]
}
```

However, when I create a new `Task` how should I create the task *and* the reference?

If I do it like this, the task could be created successfully, but creating the reference could fail, resulting in an orphaned `Task`.

```
 Task.create({
    name: taskName
  }, (err, task) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    Project
      .findOne({ _id: projectId })
      .then((project) => {
        project.tasks.push(task._id);
      });
  });
```

I'm aware MongoDB now supports Multi-Document ACID Transactions, however I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way to accomplish this, perhaps through aggregation?

I'm open to your suggestions on how best to handle this. I'm using Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mongoose middleware`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for situations like these. Wire the `save` [`post`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) hook and after you create the task insert the object id in the project `tasks` array.

```
schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  // use the doc._id now to insert into `Project.tasks` etc
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! Will this prevent orphaned tasks (say, if the middleware fails to create the reference)?

Comment: There always is a chance when working without transactions this to happen. To make sure you are safe from those just switch to transactions. If the answer helped you consider accepting it or upvoting so others can find it easier etc.